# Calcular la media de un array multidimensional

Tags: php

Pues no se como hacer para que me salga la media a partir del codigo que tengo, de momento he conseguido hacer que se imprima por pantalla.

```
<?php
$valores = [1,2,[3,[4,5]],9,[56],7];

function imprime($array){
    foreach($array as $valor){
        if(is_array($valor)){
            imprime($valor);
        }else echo $valor;
    }
}

imprime($valores);


?>
```

Comment: La media de todos los elementos del array?, por otro lado no te la calcula por que de momento no lo estás haciendo, por favor clarifica mas tu pregunta

Comment: Pues lo que quiero es sacar la media, pero no se como hacerlo con el array multidimensional

Comment: ¿Qué sería para ti la *media* en ese array? Hay ahí varios niveles de anidación y el concepto *media* en dicha estructura debe ser definido. Si es posible, danos un ejemplo del valor que esperarías y qué criterios has usado para calcular dicho valor al que llamaremos *media*.

Comment: Primero debes aprender a recorrer un arreglo multidimensional, para luego obtener sus valores y hacer lo que quieras con ellos. [link](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=571:count-php-funcion-recorrer-arreglos-o-arrays-uni-o-multidimensionales-con-for-y-foreach-ejemplo-cu00826b&catid=70&Itemid=193#:~:text=Para%20recorrer%20un%20array%20multidimensional,php.)

Comment: Cuando digo media me refiero la los numeros que hay en el array que saque la media del total de esos valores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo probé hay que pasarle el valor de una forma recursiva para que siempre lleve la cuenta

```
<?php
$valores = [
    1,2,[3,[4,5,6,7,8,9,]],10,[11],12];



function imprime($array, $i){
    
    foreach($array as $valor){
        if(is_array($valor)){
            $i = imprime($valor, $i);
        }else {
            $i = $i+1;
            echo" |". $valor;
        }
    }
    return $i;
}
$i = 0;
$valores2 = imprime($valores, $i);

echo "<br> total de elementos ".$valores2;// para array de profundidad 3 como esta en el ejemplo
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo con la clase [RecursiveArrayIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php), la funcion [array_sum()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-sum.php) y la funcion [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.count.php)

ejemplo:

```
function media($arr){
    $result=[];
    
    $i = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
    
    foreach($i as $v) {
      $result[] = $v;
    }
    
    $size = count($result);
    $sum = array_sum($result);
    return $size/$sum;
}

$valores = [1,2,[3,[4,5]],9,[56],7];
print_r(media($valores));
```

Comment: Eso era lo que me faltaba muchisimas gracias